# How to display custom news from other news providers?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I want to show news from news providers of my choice to users on my drupal site. Imagine a horizontal news ticker block on the front page with individual news from different news providers. I am using drupal 7.50.

Some more details: I just want to know the way to grab/fetch/retrieve news from websites like cnn, al-jazeerah, etc of my choice to my drupal site and show them in a slider. For example yahoo has a nice news slider. I have views ticker and views slideshow modules, but it is not necessary I use them if other modules fulfill the purpose.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what do you need, you need to modifiy the view? a custom module? the javascript to create the slide? And also just "tag" your question with "7"

Comment: I just want to know the way to grab/fetch/retrieve news from websites like cnn, al-jazeerah and etc etc of my choice to my drupal site and show them in a slider. For example yahoo has a nice news slider. I have views ticker and views slideshow modules, but it is not necessary I use them if other modules fulfill the purpose.

Comment: Just use views slideshow

Comment: It can't be done ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could import RSS feeds from cnn etc as nodes or aggregate the feed using the [feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)